# Крик отчаяния от беспомощности

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, веб-программирование, frontend

Народ, прошу вашей помощи. Я хочу стать веб-разработчиком.

Однажды, около года назад, я поняла что меня не устраивает моя жизнь. Ещё в бытность мою студентом меня завораживали люди умеющие делать красивые сайты и вот, я решила что я смогу стать веб-разработчиком. За плечами прочитанные книги по JS, по HTML, по CSS. И ведь вроде бы всё понимаю, но когда начинаю читать статьи о фронтенд-разработке, о бэкенд-разработке постоянно сталкиваюсь с кучей непонятных терминов: SASS, FSS, Angular, node.js, jquery,backbone, параллаксы, слайдеры, анимация, репозитории, react и многое другое. И тогда наступает отчаяние.

Я понимаю что очень многого не знаю, что источников очень много и что мне делать, о чем читать, что изучать.

Я понимаю JS отчасти, но не понимаю что такое параллакс к примеру, или слайдеры. Я не знаю что такое анимация и с чем её есть. Я не знаю что такое бэкенд и как его готовить. Нет, я знаю что это серверная часть веб-приложения, но с чего начать не знаю. Просто опускаются руки, мне кажется что этого не постичь никогда. Все статьи оперируют фреймворками и все говорят что никому JS не нужен.

Подскажите советом, как быть. Где брать опыт JS, реально готова удалённо за бесплатно работать, лишь бы нарабатывать опыт участия в проектах. Но никому не нужна. Всем нужны от 2-3 лет и играми в портфолио.

Это крик души и я не знаю что хочу у вас получить. Написание мобильных веб-приложений, написание веб-приложений ... что это и как? Куда идти, упорно грызть гранит, но ведь без опыта все уходит. Нужны задачи, которые можно было бы решать. Откуда, вы, профессиональные веб-разработчики и разработчики-любители берете опыт, как вы понимаете что не стоит вашего времени, а о чем стоит читать. Где посмотреть разработку любого веб-приложения с нуля до конца в виде видео чтобы понять как это происходит.

Простите за сумбур, но реально сижу и реву.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53181/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Comment: Привет. Переходите в чат. Тема вопроса не подходит для этого сайта, а вот чат как раз хорош для этого.